# Getting row count total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently, I've got three columns of lot data. Each lot has common value set with different date stamps. I'm trying to get a count of the groupings per the common value set.
example below: Table name = Data1

```
 Position     Lot       Date                      
    1         ABCD       2021-10-01 15:00.000
    1         ABCD       2021-10-01 15:30.000
    1         ABCD       2021-10-01 15:45.000
    2         ABCDE      2021-10-01 19:00.000
    2         ABCDE      2021-10-01 19:56.000
    2         ABCDE      2021-10-01 20:00.000

Output expected would be:
 Position    Count    Lot
    1          3     ABCD
    2          3     ABCDE

Select DISTINCT COUNT(POSITION) AS COUNT, LOT
FROM DATA1
GROUP BY POSITION;
```

I get a 2 count instead of 3.

Comment: The example query is invalid in SQL Server it results in an error of` `Column 'DATA1.Lot' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`  so I don't know how it could possibly return a count of 2.

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` applies to the whole resultset and is usually applied incorrectly. Based on the 6 rows of sample data, my first guess is:

```
SELECT Position, Lot, [Count] = COUNT(*) 
  FROM dbo.Data1
  GROUP BY Position, Lot;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
SELECT Position, COUNT(Position) AS Count, Lot
FROM  DATA1
GROUP BY Position, Lot
```